# ::before pseudo element creates text wrapping when using % margin compared to static margin

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, pseudo-element

So I'm having issues with a navigation bar. I want to separate each li with a "/" character and want the spacing to be based on the width of the window. When the margin of the ::before element ("/") was `margin: 0 20px;` the elements were all inline. However, when I change it to `margin: 0 14.284%;` the li content gets dropped below the slash.

How can I make everything in the li stay on one line and just be wider but still have that responsive spacing between elements.

I've provided a jsfiddle example at: http://jsfiddle.net/vDL9w/3/

EDIT:  I guess the main question I have is why does a percent drop the other text and how can I make it fluid instead of just responsive?

Answer (score 0):

what about using **em** unit instead of percentages

```
.nav-menu > li::before {
        content: "/";
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 1em; /* using ems */
}
```

you can use ems to control the margins

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/vDL9w/5/

just adjust the margin **em** value to your liking of space needed between li's.. (ie.. 1.2em or 0.9 .. etc..)

> The **em** unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size' property of the element on which it is used.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#em-unit

:)

Comment: I was hoping for it to be more fluid with window resizing. otherwise it would be media queries the size with fixed em values as well. I also am more not sure why the text is being dropped below the slash when the margin is the same equivalent px size.

Comment: if you are using media queries than just setup a media queries css rule for the font-size on the LI element .. since ems get their value based on the font-size of the element. .. or does your font-size for your LI elements stay the same when window resizing?

Comment: I could use a bunch of media queries, but I'm trying to make it fluid at the largest, media query to remove the "/", and a media query to make it a dropdown menu on mobile devices. I guess the main question i have is why does a percent drop the other text and how can i make it fluid instead of responsive. i'll edit my question.